# Изменение переменной с интервалом в 5 секунд

Tags: javascript, время

Я хочу добавлять в переменную 5 монет каждые 5 секунд. Извините, я не очень хорошо говорю на русском.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let coins = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  coins += 5;
  console.log(coins);
}, 5000);
```